# How to Retrieve data form many to many relation in laravel4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Business Modal

```
class Business extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Services');
    }
}
```

Service Modal

```
class Service extends \Eloquent {


    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Business');
    }


    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag','service_tags','service_id','tag_id');
    }
}
```

Tag Modal

```
class Tag extends \Eloquent {

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Service','service_tags','service_id','tag_id');
    }
}
```

Now i want to retrieve the services of a business by the tag id.
So how can i do it ????

Comment: could you explain ur question more, do you want businesses by tag id or business's services which have the particular tag id?

Comment: actually i have business and all the services of that business.now i want to sort the services by the tag

Comment: if you are asking that, then your question is wrong, please modify that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Service::whereHas('tag', function($query) use ($tagId) {
    $query->where('tag_id', '=', $tagId);
})->get();
```

Edit: Changed the answer.
Previous Answer:

```
Business::with(['services')->whereHas('tag', function($query) use ($tagId) {
    $query->where('tag_id', '=', $tagId);
})->get()
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tag() happen.What do i do now

Comment: if i write like this 
$business->service->whereHas('tag', function($query) use ($tagId) {
    $query->where('tag_id', '=', $tagId);
})->get();

will it work

Comment: You could try and see. But use `$business->service()` instead of `$business->service` (with the parenthesis)

Comment: Try this. If you want services by business. Not tested. `Business::with(['service' => funciton($query) {
   $query->whereHas('tag', function($query) use ($tagId) {
        $query->where('tag_id', '=', $tagId);
    }) 
}])->get();`

Comment: this i not working because of some syntax error.Dude can you just tell me the logic so that i can do it by my self

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79955/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-chanafdo).